# Generative story for a variational auto encoder

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, bayesian, autoencoders, variational-bayes

I am reading a tutorial on [variational autoencoder](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.05908). In any inference problem we make assumptions about the underlying process of data generation. In VAE's, The tutorial states that data is generated based on the equation

$$P(X) = \int P(X|z)p(z)dz$$

I would like to clarify how the underlying data is generated. Since $X$ the data is fixed, $P(X)$ is a constant.

Repeat multiple times (approximation)

1. Sample $z \sim N(0,I)$
2. Compute the likelihood of the data whereby $X = \{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$
   and $P(X|z) = \prod_{i=1}^NN(x_i|f(z;\theta),\sigma^2*I)$

Take average over all sampled values of $z$ to compute data likelihood $P(X)$.

If my understanding is correct, It seems counterintuitive that in one sample of $z$, it is able to explain the likelihood over all training data in $P(X|Z)$.

Suppose $z=[0.1,0.5]$ for simplicity, and I use MNIST data of digit handwritings of 1-9. Then this particular $z$ value should be able to generate digits from 1-9 in the dataset ? How can this one value generate digits that are different from each other.

This is my understanding of the generative modelling. Correct me ifI am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generative story describes how each image sample is generated. The story is as follows - (a) Sample z ~ N(z | 0, I); (b) Sample x ~ N(x | f_mu(z), f_sig(z))

For any generative story, going forward tells us about test time, and going backwards helps us learn the parameters (note that last step has `x`, our data).

Every model comes with its assumptions. The implicit assumption in VAE is : z-space is cleaved in such a way that different regions give different digits. Our goal is to figure out these regions. This is the "Encoder part".

We need to optimize the log-marginal-likelihood $logP(x)=log \Pi_i\int_z p(x_i | z)p(z)dz $. Let's say `x_i` is `7`. Most of $p(x_i | z)$'s are going to be zero -- because most of the `z`'s don't even give `7`. We have "assumed" that only certain regions of z-space give `7`. You are cluelessly computing $p(x_i | z)$ for `z`'s that belong to `1,2,3`etc clusters (because of $\int_z$ part). Encoder (parameterized by $\phi$) helps us to not be clueless. At training time, you encode `x_i` to z-space, and then decode it back to x-space. The math looks like this --

$$logP(x)=log \Pi_i\int_z \frac{p(x_i | z)q_{\phi}(z | x)p(z)}{q_{\phi}(z | x)}dz = \Sigma_i log\int_z \frac{p(x_i | z)q_{\phi}(z | x)p(z)}{q_{\phi}(z | x)}dz
$$
Notice that we have an expectation wrt encoder `q_phi` inside log. So use Jensen inequality log(Expectation) >= Expectation(log) to get
$$log P(x) \geq \Sigma_i E_{q_{\phi}}[log\frac{p(x_i, z)}{q_{\phi}(z|x)} ]$$
where RHS is the **ELBO** term. Effectively, (x_i)----$q_{\phi}$----(z)----$p_{\theta}$----(x_i)

Intuitively, the encoder `q` figures out how to take `x` to `z` in such a way that `z` is "rich" (cleaved), and the decoder `p` (parameterized by $\theta$) figures out to take `z` from this "rich" z-space to `x`.

At test time, you can't use encoder to take `x` to `z`. You don't even have `x` - your target is to generate `x`. So, you sample some random `z` from N(z | 0, I). From your question, let's say $z = [0.1, 0.5]$. The decoder $p_{\theta}$ "knows" that this z-space is rich, and the `z` you've sampled belongs to the `3` cluster (say). Hence, we generate the digit x = `3`.

You sample some other `z`. The decoder figures that this belongs to the `1` cluster, and it generates x = `1`.

Can just a 2-dimensional z-space be "rich" enough so that different regions correspond to each of the 10 digits? Maybe not. You trained your model assuming that it can.

Comment: hi @stbv thank you for your help. I think I sort of understand but I am still not sure. The encoder takes the data $x$ and maps it to the standard normal that we wish to sample from. The decoder is trained to output the original data $x$ from this standard normal distribution. Hence, the decoder essentially is trained to decode the original image from the standard normal $Z$ space ?

Comment: Yes, that is the training phase. Autoencoder family of models work like that. For example, in denoising autoencoder the input is (orig image + noise). Encoder takes this to z-space, and the decoder is trained to recover orig image (without noise).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing up

1. How to compute or approximately compute $P(X)$
2. The "generative story"

Also, I might be wrong on this, but based on the last paragraph, it sounds like you're confusing $X$ with the entire dataset, whereas the notation in the article you linked uses $X$ to mean just one point in the dataset. $x_i$ are meant to be the individual components of vector $X$.

The two steps you described are one way to compute (1) -- density at some single data point $X$. As it turns out, this is too inefficient in practice, so people use the "variational lower bound", or "ELBO", to obtain a non stochastic, non exact, but guaranteed lower bound on $P(X)$.

The generative story goes like this:

1. we sample some $z$ from a distribution $p(z)$, usually standard normal.
2. compute $\mu = f(z;\theta)$
3. we draw $X$ from $P(X|z)$ -- to be more precise, we draw from a normal distribution with the previously computed mean $\mu$.

Also regarding the last paragraph: you can abstractly think of $z$ as some "blueprint" for the generated data $X$. According to our generative story, a single $z$ can result in different $X$, because there's some randomness involved. And it is possible, although extremely unlikely, that a $z$ which usually generates the digit "3" might somehow generate the digit "8", because randomness is involved.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification regarding X being one datapoint. however, since $z$ is drawn from $N(0,1)$, I am still struggling to understand how samples from $N(0,1)$ can generate all the data(eg. MNIST digits). It would make more intuitive sense if the $z's$ used to generate different digits come from different distribution

Comment: Suppose you had a different $z$ distribution for each digit, and then suppose you had an even [mixture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution) of all those 10 distributions so you could draw a digit at random. Whatever this distribution is, as long as it's "reasonable", you can always convert it to a unit gaussian using some transform $f$. Plus, our neural network is sufficiently powerful that we can imagine it has such $f$ built-in, or learned. So we might as well use unit gaussian for simplicity.

Comment: But the neural network does not compute the transform $f$ ? the $f$ is only used to map $z$ to $\mu$

Comment: I overloaded the symbol $f$ by accident there, call it $g$ instead

Comment: Might you know why for a single data point $X$, the marginal probability $P(X)$ needs to be an integral over the whole probability space $z$ ? (as mentioned in the tutorial) surely there would be some regions of the $z$ space that do not "represent" the single datapoint. This would lead to low likelihoods and for regions which "represent" the single data point, it would lead to high likelihoods.

Comment: @calveeen i'm confused by your question a bit. you can think of it like this: people initially defined the joint density $P(X,z)$ because they wanted a very flexible model. however, to get $P(X)$, you need to marginalize out $z$ -- and whenever you want to marginalize something out, you integrate over it. So there "needs to be an integral" because of the laws of probability.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of how $P(X)$ is calculated. Suppose that $X$ represented one image of the digit "2". The generative process requires sampling $z$ from the prior, not all parts of the $z$ space will contain latent attributes of the digit "2", but the equation says that we still have to integrate over the whole $z$ space. It feels weird that the integral is also considered in parts of the $z$ space that are unlikely to contain the latent attributes of the digit "2".